# Does /arch:AVX enable AVX2?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, vectorization, avx2

Does `/arch:AVX` enable AVX2 (with 256-bit integer SIMD instructions and some new FP shuffles) on the Visual Studio 2012 Update 4?

Line of thought:

- Yes, it enables AVX because VS doesn't mention AVX2. But I think VS can do AVX2 because my intrinsic work.
- No, it doesn't because AVX and AVX2 are separate CPU features
  (Sandybridge vs. Haswell, or Excavator/Zen vs. Bulldozer),
  just like SSE and SSE2 are separate

[image: AVX2]

Comment: VS 2012 has the AVX2 intrinsics. So you can just use them. You only need `/arch:AVX` to enable the VEX-encoding. So if `/arch:AVX2` even exists, it's to allow the compiler to automatically use them - which I doubt it will be able to since VS has had a history of lagging behind on auto-vectorization.

Comment: @Mysticial `ignoring unknown option '/arch:AVX2'` :-(

Comment: Note that support for ``/arch:AVX2`` is included with [Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 or later](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/02/28/avx2-support-in-visual-studio-c-compiler.aspx) and [Visual Studio 2015 Technical Preview](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/11/12/visual-studio-2015-preview-now-available.aspx).

Comment: AVX has 256-bit registers, but only FP instructions (including FP shuffles) are extended to 256b.  AVX2 adds 256b versions of integer instructions, as well as some new lane-crossing shuffles (for FP as well as integer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It refers to AVX not AVX2. According to Microsoft this applies (mostly) to floating point operations.
VS2012 supports AVX2 intrinsic functions regardless of this flag.
AVX is available on i3, i5 and i7 variants of SandyBridge and IvyBridge.
AVX2 started with Haswell.

Answer (score 1):

The using of "/arch:AVX" compiler options allows to use AVX2 integer instructions more efficiently. If this options is disabled then code with AVX2 instructions may be slower then with SSE2 (because there are many switchings between SSE2  and AVX2).

Comment: Is this true, several previous posts say that the AVX switch will not turn on autovectorizaiton features targeting AVX2?

Comment: @Mikhail: I'm pretty sure this answer is saying that code-gen for AVX2 *intriniscs* will be better if you use `/arch:AVX`.  Not that it will let the compiler invent uses of AVX2 instructions on its own; that would require `/arch:AVX2`.  (Older MSVC that was current at the time created SSE/AVX transition stalls if you used AVX or AVX2 intrinsics without `/arch:AVX`.  IIRC modern MSVC is better).

Answer (score 0):

I have already confirmed that Visual Studio 2013 Update 5, when /arch:AVX
is enabled, still compiles certain part of the code into AVX2, currently
there is no option to say AVX only, which I hope Microsoft would fix.

Comment: If true this could be a big problem, do you have any references or examples?